# Create generic method to retrieve entities by different properties

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two methods that are fairly similar. I want to return entities based on whether one of its properties is null or an empty string. However, the properties of the entities are not shared. All properties are strings.

```
public List<Phone> GetPhones(){
    return context.Phones
                  .Where(p=> !(p.Number == null
                       || p.Number.Trim() == String.Empty))
                  .ToList();

public List<Remote> GetRemotes(){
    return context.Remotes
                  .Where(r => !(r.OEM == null
                       || r.OEM.Trim() == String.Empty))
                  .ToList();
}
```

Is it possible to create a method like:

```
public List<T> GetEntities(string property){
    return ...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get property value from string using reflection in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the string properties can be done via reflection: 
[Get property value from string using reflection in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

The problem with what you're trying to do is that the *source* of the objects is different for each call, in addition to the property being accessed.  To write a generic function you'll have to provide the source to the method as well as the property name.

A better approach might be to write a helper method that takes the source and a lambda expression to get the appropriate property:

```
public List<T> GetListOfNonEmpties<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, string> property)
{
    return source.Where(n => !(property(n) == null
                        || property(n).Trim() == String.Empty))
                    .ToList();
}
```

Then use that in your other methods like this:

```
public static List<Phone> GetPhones()
{
    return GetListOfNonEmpties(context.Phones, p => p.Number);
}

public static List<Remote> GetRemotes()
{
    return GetListOfNonEmpties(context.Remotes, r => r.OEM);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, this looks really clean.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the following is probably a better general solution for you:

```
public IQueryable<Phone> GetPhones(){
    return context.Phones
                  .Where(p=> !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.Number));
}

public IQueryable<Remote> GetRemotes(){
    return context.Remotes
                  .Where(r => !String.IsNullorWhiteSpace(r.OEM));
}
```

It returns an IQueryable instead of List, so incase you want to put further restrictions on it, the execution can be delayed to include them as well.  A "helper" function to generalize the functionality you are asking for isn't shorter or more concise than just using the String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace function on string.  Assuming your context is a database, particularly a remote database, this is a significant improvement.  If you don't have further restrictions now, you might (probably will?) in the future.